# How to change working directory of a child process by posix_spawn?

Tags: process, fork, pwd

In Linux (CentOS 7.5, kernel 3.10, gcc 7.3), is it possible to change the working directory of a child process created by [posix_spawn](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/posix_spawn.html) before it runs a given process image (an executable)? If yes, how? If no, what is the best practice to do it?

Comment: There is no ["best practice"](https://lwn.net/Articles/360556/) in this case.

Comment: Never seen `posix_spawn` (outside of job interviews), what's wrong with `fork`/`chdir`/`exec` ?

Comment: Which OS? It's not in POSIX. Can do on Solaris, but I don't think Linux supports it.

Comment: @MarkPlotnick, Linux.

Comment: @thrig, nothing! Just looking for a good solution. fork/chdir/exec could be an answer, I was wondering whether there is a better (more straightforward/cleaner) way to do it.

Comment: @ThomasDickey. Thank you for the link. It looks like that is the answer to my question!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no way to do thisas part of the `posix_spawn()` set of functions.

There is an ongoing discussion initiated by redhat whether such a feature should be added. If this gets accepted, it could become part of POSIX in the next version - this may be in 2-3 years.

BTW: `posix_spawn()` is implemented on top of `vfork()/exec()` and as long as you don't like to implement a POSIX shell with `vfork()` support,  `vfork()/exec()` is really easy to use.